# Proof request for finding the area of a rectangle using an ellipse and an integral.

Tags: integration, geometry, proof-verification, proof-explanation

$$\frac{\int_{-a}^a (-\frac ba \sqrt{a^2-x^2} + b\;)\mathrm{d}x + \frac{\pi ab}2}2=ab$$
The above equation finds the area of a rectangle given A and B (both > 0). I wrote this myself as a challenge. Using desmos I verified that it was true ([the desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ljqlfk5lgb)). I was wondering if someone could write a proof for that because I  <s>suck at proofs</s> have tried and failed to write one. The main issue is dealing with the square root part of the equation. If anyone would write a proof with a description of the process I would be very thankful.

### Note:

This is not for homework, I am just making challenges for myself to find area of objects in new ways. I also wrote one for finding the area of a square using integrals and message me on chat or something if you want to see it.

#### How I found it:

I found the above equation by making a inscribed ellipse in a rectangle. I then found the area under the bottom half of the ellipse if you translate it to be tangent to the x axis. I added the area of the ellipse divided by 2 and divided the sum by 2 (why I did this is fuzzy because I had to tweak the formula to get it to be correct I am planning on asking about why it is like this later).

Comment: I didn't put the equation in the title because I felt it would clutter it up if it should be there tell me and I will place it

Comment: It's very cool that you put together this experiment.  For the proof, it's sufficient to show $$\int_{-a}^{a}\frac{b}{a}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\,dx = \frac{\pi ab}{2}$$  Can you do that?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang OP struggled precisely with this part (sqrt). I don't think that equation would help him a lot.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire: In the integral I wrote, the integrand is nonnegative, so the integral is too.  I wanted to trim the algebra down to the essential part of the calculation.  I should have noticed the OP said he was having trouble with precisely that part.  Even so, I think simplifying it down to that one sqrt at least isolates the confusion.

Comment: $$\int_{-a}^{a}\frac{b}{a}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\,dx = \frac{\pi ab}{2}$$ is true since the area of the ellipse is simply $\pi ab$

Answer (score 1):

It is true:

We want to show, on rearranging your equality, that $$\int_{-a}^a \left(-\frac ba \sqrt{a^2-x^2} + b\right)\, \mathrm{d}x=\left(2-\frac\pi2\right)ab$$ The LHS is equivalent to $$-\frac ba \int_{-a}^a\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\, \mathrm{d}x+\left[bx\right]_{-a}^a=-\frac ba \left[\frac{x\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}2+\frac{a^2}2\sin^{-1}\frac xa\right]_{-a}^a+2ab$$ (integrate by parts by writing $f(x)=\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ and $g'(x)=1$) or $$-\frac ba\left[\frac{a^2}2\cdot \frac \pi2-\frac{a^2}2\cdot\left(-\frac\pi2\right)\right]+2ab=2ab-\frac ba\left(\frac{\pi a^2}{2}\right)=\left(2-\frac\pi2\right)ab$$ as required.

Answer (score 1):

To evaluate $\int_{-a}^a \frac{b}{a}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\,dx$, I recommend a trigonometric substitution $x= a \sin \theta$.  Then $dx = a \cos\theta\,d\theta$ and $\sqrt{a^2-x^2} = a \cos\theta$.  When $x=-a$, $\sin\theta = -1$, so $\theta =-\frac{\pi}{2}$.  When $x=a$, $\sin\theta = 1$, so $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$.  So
\begin{align*}
    \int_{-a}^a \frac{b}{a}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\,dx
    &= \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{b}{a} (a \cos\theta)(a \cos\theta\,d\theta)
     = ab \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos^2\theta\,d\theta
\end{align*}
For this integral, we use a trig identity:
$$
    ab \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos^2\theta\,d\theta
    = \frac{ab}{2}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} (1+\cos2\theta)\,d\theta
$$
Over the interval $\left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$, $\cos2\theta$ makes a full period.  So the integral of this piece is zero.  What's left is $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} 1\,d\theta$, which is clearly $\pi$.  So 
$$
    \frac{ab}{2}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} (1+\cos2\theta)\,d\theta = \frac{\pi ab}{2}
$$
and we are done.